# Q: Count array pairs with bitwise AND > k ~ better than O(N^2) possible?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, bit-manipulation

Given an array `nums`

**Count** no. of pairs (two elements) where **bitwise AND** is greater than `K`

Brute force

```py
for i in range(0,n):
   for j in range(i+1,n):
       if a[i]&a[j] > k:
           res += 1
```

Better version:
preprocess to remove all elements `≤k`
and then brute force

But i was wondering, what would be the limit in complexity here?

Can we do better with a trie, hashmap approach like two-sum?

( I did not find this problem on Leetcode so I thought of asking here )

Comment: Could any elements of the array be negative? If so you shouldn't remove them as, eg in 16 bits 0xffff & 0x7fff is 0x7fff

Comment: Hmm, you could use a solution to this problem plus inclusion-exclusion to solve the [Orthogonal Vectors Problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.02824.pdf), so getting a significantly subquadratic solution without falsifying the Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis (big open question in complexity theory) would be difficult. When problems like this come up in competitive programming there's usually a constraint on the word size that unlocks the [sum over subsets technique](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/45223).

Comment: @yozaam: Source of this question please?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni go to the #interview-experience channel, someone has shared it in the second last message they got it in an Online Assesment 

website link : [http://binarysearch.com/](http://binarysearch.com/)

Comment: @dmuir i did not think of that, nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let size_of_input_array = `N`. Let the input array be of `B`-bit numbers

Here is an easy to understand and implement solution.

[image]

- Eliminate all values <= k.
- The above image shows 5 10-bit numbers.

**Step 1: Adjacency Graph**

- Store a list of set bits. In our example, 7th bit is set for numbers at index 0,1,2,3 in the input array.

**Step 2: The challenge is to avoid counting the same pairs again.**

To solve this challenge we take help of union-find data structure as shown in the code below.

```
//unordered_map<int, vector<int>> adjacency_graph;
//adjacency_graph has been filled up in step 1

vector<int> parent;
for(int i = 0; i < input_array.size(); i++)
    parent.push_back(i);

int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < adjacency_graph.size(); i++){ // loop 1
    auto v = adjacency_graph[i];
    if(v.size() > 1){
        int different_parents = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < v.size(); j++) { // loop 2
            int x = find(parent, v[j]);
            int y = find(parent, v[j - 1]);
            if (x != y) {
                different_parents++;
                union(parent, x, y);
            }
        }
        result += (different_parents * (different_parents - 1)) / 2;
    }
}
return result;
```

In the above code, `find` and `union` are from union-find data structure.

**Time Complexity:**

Step 1:

```
Build Adjacency Graph: O(BN)
```

Step 2:

```
Loop 1: O(B)
Loop 2: O(N * Inverse of Ackermann’s function which is an extremely slow-growing function)
```

Overall Time Complexity

```
= O(BN)
```

**Space Complexity**

```
Overall space complexity = O(BN)
```

Comment: "rest of the part is easy" isn't what OP is looking for. Also, it isn't as straightforward as you think, so kindly explain as well

Comment: @גלעדברקן Somewhere I had a doubt if parent array logic would work all the time. I've changed it to use union-find. Help me with time-complexity. I assume Inverse Ackermann is going to be amortized theta(1) in our case.

Comment: I wish a bounty was offered for this solution. Quite a hard work. 

Comment: Thank you @ShridharRKulkarni how do I give a bounty?

Comment: @yozaam: You have a big ♥️. Thanks! Save your rep in your early stages of SO. Helps earning privileges and contributing to SO better.

Comment: Could you please add testable code with random input? (Or even just testable code). Based on David Eisenstat's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446860/q-count-array-pairs-with-bitwise-and-k-better-than-on2-possible#comment115711612_65446860), I'm not sure I trust this (or at least the time complexity you're suggesting) is possible.

Comment: I am curious about the concern you've raised and about David's comment as well. Though, I am falling short of time. You or @yozaam can test the code and report if any failing cases. Please use C++. Theoretically the solution looks good. I'll carry the work further if any failures. Also, we can start a chat along with David to understand his comment. If you understand the comment in full, please help me understand it too. I'm eager to learn about it.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I don't see where this answer uses k outside of the pruning step. Assuming no restriction on the word size (which would work around SETH using the sum over subsets technique I mentioned), we can just light up a unique high order bit for each input number and render the pruning step irrelevant (since all the numbers will be ≥ k but will have the same bitwise AND as before). Given that the rest of the algorithm seems independent of k, I have a hard time believing that it's correct. +1 to the code request.

Comment: This is getting interesting. I'll code it over the weekend. Meanwhile, if someone can code it in C++, that would be great.

Comment: Update: I could spend some time on writing the code. https://pastebin.com/TspKFyj7 I found a bug for the input I've mentioned in the code. I am trying to fix it. The issue is with checking the bits <= (int)(log2(k)). Would be great if someone can spend some time thinking on this interesting bug and I'll try it too as and when time permits. Thanks for your patience. I am also thinking on the possibility of any alternative solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, prune everything `<= k`. Also Sort the value list.

Going from the most significant bit to the least significant we are going to keep track of the set of numbers we are working with (initially all ,`s=0, e=n`).

Let p be the first position that contains a 1 in the current set at the current position.

If the bit in k is 0, then everything that would yield a 1 world definetly be good and we need to investigate the ones that get a 0. We have `(end - p) * (end-p-1) /2` pairs in the current range and  `(end-p) * <total 1s in this position larger or equal to end>` combinations with larger previously good numbers, that we can add to the solution. To continue we update `end = p`. We want to count 1s in all the numbers above, because we only counted them before in pairs with each other, not with the numbers this low in the set.

If the bit in k is 1, then we can't count any wins yet, but we need to eliminate everything below `p`, so we update `start = p`.

You can stop once you went through all the bits or `start==end`.

Details:

- Since at each step we eliminate either everything that has a 0 or everything that has a 1, then everything between start and end will have the same bit-prefix. since the values are sorted we can do a binary search to find `p`.
- For `<total 1s in this position larger than p>`. We already have the values sorted. So we can compute partial sums and store for every position in the sorted list the number of 1s in every bit position for all numbers above it.

Complexity:

- We got bit-by-bit so L (the bit length of the numbers), we do a binary search (logN), and lookup and updates O(1), so this is O(L logN).
- We have to sort O(NlogN).
- We have to compute partial bit-wise sums O(L*N).

Total O(L logN + NlogN + L*N).

Since N>>L, `L logN` is subsummed by `NlogN`. Since L>>logN (probably, as in you have 32 bit numbers but you don't have 4Billion of them), then `NlogN` is subsummed by `L*N`. So complexity is **O(L * N)**. Since we also need to keep the partial sums around the memory complexity is also O(L * N).